# VB.Net Word Mutillevel list

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am programmatically changing some styles and adding multilevel numbering to achieve a "Title, Sub Title... etc." structure. Everything works, the style are right, the numbering works through the levels.

When the styles are used just on their own they line up fine to where I want them but when the numbering code is used a 1.52cm indent is put in from somewhere and is overriding the indent code of the Style.

The style code is run after the numbering code and so should overwrite any defaults that I missing.

My code is below if anyone can give me a hand.

```
Private Sub doSReport()

    Dim application As Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim numberlist = application.ListGalleries(WdListGalleryType.wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1)

    With numberlist
        .Name = ""
        With .ListLevels(1)
            .NumberFormat = "%1."
            .NumberStyle = WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic
            .NumberPosition = 0
            .TextPosition = 21
            .TabPosition = 21
            .ResetOnHigher = 0
            .StartAt = 1
            .LinkedStyle = "Heading 1"
        End With

        With .ListLevels(2)
            .NumberFormat = "%1.%2."
            .NumberStyle = WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic
            .NumberPosition = 0
            .TextPosition = 29
            .TabPosition = 29
            .ResetOnHigher = 1
            .StartAt = 1
            .LinkedStyle =  "Heading 2"
        End With

        With .ListLevels(3)
            .NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3"
            .NumberStyle = WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic
            .NumberPosition = 0
            .TextPosition = 36
            .TabPosition = 36
            .ResetOnHigher = 2
            .StartAt = 1
            .LinkedStyle =  "Heading 3"
        End With
    End With

    With Doc.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1)
        .NameLocal = "Chapter Title"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 16
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorDarkYellow 'RGB(36, 95, 144)
        .LinkStyle = True
        .QuickStyle = True
        .Visibility = False
        .Priority = 3
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0
        .ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = 21.54
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 12
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
        .ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore = True
        .LinkToListTemplate(numberlist, 1)
    End With

    With Doc.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2)
        .NameLocal = "Chapter Subheading"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Color = RGB(36, 95, 144)
        .LinkStyle = True
        .QuickStyle = True
        .Visibility = False
        .Priority = 4
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0
        .ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = -29
        .LinkToListTemplate(numberlist, 2)
    End With

    With Doc.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading3)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Italic = True
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Color = RGB(36, 95, 144)
        .LinkStyle = True
        .QuickStyle = True
        .Visibility = False
        .Priority = 5
        .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0
        .ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = -36
        .LinkToListTemplate(numberlist, 3)
    End With
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: The styles that are coded have the correct amount of indentation to be used, these work fine. When I then add the code to use the number list the wording on the screen, when I apply the Style, indents by 1.52cm when I don't want it to. I can Manually adjust the style to remove the indent so I know it doesn't have to be indented but I can't work out where in my code to set it not to indent.

Comment: then what is the issue ?

Comment: I can't seem to find any properties of either ListTemplates or ListLevels that refers to indentation. There is Listlevels.TextPosition but changing this doesn't seem to have any effect and wouldn't account for all 3 levels of the multilevel list indenting by the same amount. Do you know where in the ListTemplate object I can set, or in this case, zero any indentation when numbering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbering style indenting overrides paragaph style indenting - always, no matter in what order it's applied. So you need to work with the indenting specified in the ListTemplate.

As in the dialog box for setting up numbering, there are three settings that determine where the number and text are positioned: `NumberPosition`, `TabPosition` and `TextPosition`. You can read more in the object model Help and compare to the settings in the dialog box.

Keep in mind that Word calculates these (and many, many other) settings in Points. We, of course, think in centimeters (or inches). Word makes it easy for us by providing conversion functions such as `CentimetersToPoint` (and the reverse, as well as `InchesToPoints` and the reverse). Note that these can only be used when the project has a reference to the Word COM library ("early-binding").

```
Sub ListTemplatePlusHeadingIndents()
    Dim doc As word.Document = ActiveDocument
    Dim lt As word.ListTemplate = doc.ListTemplates.Add(True, "LT_Test")
    Dim sH1 As word.style = doc.styles(wdStyleHeading1)
    Dim sH2 As word.style= doc.styles(wdStyleHeading2)
    Dim indentLvlBase as Double = 0
    Dim indentLvl1 as Double = Word.CentimetersToPoints(0.7)
    Dim indentLvl2 as Double = 2 * indentLvl1

    With lt.ListLevels(1)
        .LinkedStyle = sH1
        .NumberPosition = indentLvlBase
        .TabPosition = indentLvl1 
        .TextPosition = indentLvl1
    End With
    With lt.ListLevels(2)
        .LinkedStyle = sH2
        .NumberPosition = indentLvl1
        .TabPosition = indentLvl2 
        .TextPosition = indentLvl2 
    End With        
End Sub
```

Comment: I was already trying to set the Number,Tab and Text position in my code using the number of points (21,29,36 etc.) and it wasn't working. Yet when I use the CentimetersToPoints function in a variable and then assign it then works. Thanks for the assist again Cindy!

Comment: @MattBartlett Yeah, I saw that, but figured I'd try it anyway... Never occurred to me it would be the CentimetersToPoints you were missing! I'll add a mention of that in the Answer text since it is a very Word-y thing!